# Code problem: cPanel cron job for running php script to execute a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, cron

I need to run a MySQL stored procedure daily. I do it manually now from Workbench. I would like to automate that process. Running it as a scheduled events within MySQL phpMyAdmin is not available to me. 
GoDaddy offers a  cron job command line within cPanel that can run a php script. I have researched everything I can but cannot figure out the right combination to make this work. Needless to say, I am new at this. The php code has been borrowed from online coding tutorials.

The only thing I am sure of as far as code is concerned is the call to a stored procedure function that I run from Workbench. The stored procedure takes some complicated queries and makes static tables that are accessed by users on the front end. And I do know how to set the cron job run times, no problem.

Could you please tell me what I need to change to make the call function work?

The cPanel cron job command line reads:

`/usr/bin/php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/cron/sp_run.php`

The php script file reads:

```
    <?php
        $host = 'localhost';
        $username = 'USERNAME';
        $password = 'PASSWORD';
        $dbname = 'DBNAME';


            try {
                $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                // assign the execute stored procedure to the variable
                $sql = 'CALL DBNAME.sp_make_tables()';
                // execute the stored procedure
                $q = $pdo->query($sql);
                $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die("Error occurred:" . $e->getMessage());
            }
    ?>
```

My shared server application versions are:
cPanel Version  78.0 (build 38)
Apache Version  2.4.41
PHP Version 5.6.40
MySQL Version   5.6.46-cll-lve
Architecture    x86_64
Operating System    linux

Thank you for whatever help you can offer.

Comment: A quick (but maybe dirty) workaround is to have a console php script on your local computer that sends a signal to your godaddy hosted script to execute. At whatever interval you desire. You could store the godaddy hosted script in a password protected folder and your local script would be programmed with those credentials.

Comment: That is an interesting thought but how does it get set up? Does the php code look like it should work? Is there a way to test the code without having it run through cron?

Comment: If you were to do it the way i mentioned, your *sp_run.php* would remain on your hosted server, but in a public directory, and ideally password protected folder. Then on your local setup,  have your signal php scrip executed from the console e.g. `php signal.php`. Inside your signal script make it so that it runs forever e.g. by a loop that pauses. Use *curl* to signal your *sp_run.php*. `curl_init(), curl_setopt(), curl_exec()` etc.You can specify the password with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);`.